# PHP reflection - Is an object fully constructed

Tags: php, reflection

The method newInstanceWithoutConstructor ( [Reflection Class - New Instance Without Construtctor](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) ) can be used to instantiate an object without calling its constructor.

Is there any way to determine whether this has been the case?

for example

```
$obj = new MyClass('B', 'C');
$reflect = new ReflectionClass('MyObj')
$obj2= $reflect->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
```

Is there any way to determine that `$obj` is fully constructed and `$obj2` is not?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you implement something in MyClass to check for that:

```
class MyClass {
  public $constructorCalled = false;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->constructorCalled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: `$constructorCalled` should be private. And even then it's possible to use reflection to 'cheat' it.

Comment: Because cheating would always work, I went for the simplest solution, to show the idea. Improvements to that are up to the OP

Comment: I was hoping this could be used on any class, including internal ones. The problem is, there's no way to determine if newInstanceWithoutConstructor() can be used on a given class or not (it doesn't work on internal classes, or classes that extend internal classes) ->isInternal() returns false on classes that extend internal classes but newInstanceWithoutConstructor cannot be used on them

Comment: @Tom That is a completely different problem, as described in your question. getParentClass will help you with that.